# mvn compilation error LifecycleExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, javac

I've installed maven by adding it to my path. When I run the command `mvn -v` it returns:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T10:58:13+03:00) 
Maven home: /Users/yarkoni/apache-maven-3.5.2 Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home 
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x", 
version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

To my understand in order to install I downloaded and added it to my PATH.
I then try to runt he example appEngine app locally:

```
mvn -Plocal clean appengine:devserver
```

I get the following error:

```
    [INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /Users/yarkoni/Projects/getting-started-java/bookshelf-standard/2-structured-data/target/bookshelf-standard-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes An exception has occurred in the compiler (9-internal). 
Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:712)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.isDefault(Locations.java:546)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.isDefaultBootClassPath(Locations.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.isDefaultBootClassPath(BaseFileManager.java:204)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.validate(Arguments.java:479)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.prepareCompiler(JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.access$000(JavacTaskImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:128)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:87)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler$1.call(BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:137)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:108)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.run(ErrorProneCompiler.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne$CompilerInvoker.compile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:222)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.performCompile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:943)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:407)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:465)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3524)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.systemClasses(Locations.java:665)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.computePath(Locations.java:621)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:709)     ... 49 more
```

Comment: You JDK 9 installation is broken somehow...

Answer (score 1):

```
 java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
```

Seems like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules` is not a directory in your current file system, but it should be. Maybe a someone or something messed with your Java installation. You should make sure this path point to a directory or re-install your JDK.

Comment: Updated Java did not help

Comment: Did you check if the path was indeed a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/448). Seems like maven compiler can be used with different compilers (e.g. error-prone, plexus, etc.) and these plugins are slightly behind with JDK development.

You have 2 options:

- use JDK 8 for build
- find out what configuration you need (e.g. for [error prone](http://errorprone.info/docs/installation))

Hope this help someone, I am still investigatin myself which option is better for me.

Edit: I downgraded for now, but I plan to investigate and once I've done that I will update this answer.